# ERROR: object 'input' not found

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to draw a scatter plot between `Avg_Rating` and `Cost_per_plate`, but I get the error: "object 'input' not found". However, when I run the same command in a console, it gives the correct output.

```
output$prosv <- renderPlotly(
    result <- pros%>%filter(pros$Avg_Rating <=as.numeric(input$rating)),   
    plot_ly(result,x=~Avg_Rating,y=~Cost_per_plate,type = 
    "scatter",mode="markers")
    )
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the information . I will take care in future.

Answer (score 0):

There was a slight mistake on my part as I missed curly braces in renderPlotly() function.